# Existe um limite de dados que podem ser passados em Websocket.send?

Tags: javascript, websocket

Construi um servidor para poder implementar o [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/) do HTML5. Nessa implementação, sempre envio e recebo dados no formato `JSON`.

Porém tenho a seguinte dúvida:
Existe um tamanho limite a ser passado no método [Websocket.send](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/send)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Um único frame WebSocket, por frame base RFC-6455, tem um limite de tamanho máximo de 2 ^ 63 bytes (9.223.372.036.854.775.807 bytes ~ = 9.22 exabytes)

No entanto, uma mensagem WebSocket, composta por 1 ou mais frames, não tem limite imposto a partir do nível do protocolo.

Cada implementação do WebSocket tratará os limites de mensagem e quadro de maneira diferente. Como configurar tamanhos máximos de mensagens para toda a mensagem (geralmente por motivos de consumo de memória) ou oferecer opções de streaming para mensagens grandes para melhor utilizar a memória.

Mas, no seu caso, é provável que a implementação WebSocket escolhida tenha um bug e esteja dividindo indevidamente a mensagem JSON em várias mensagens, em vez de vários quadros. Você pode usar a ferramenta de inspeção de rede no Chrome ou uma ferramenta externa como o Wireshark para confirmar esse comportamento.

Espero ter ajudado